# React TextArea Component - How to use getInititalState() in ES6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a relatively simple snippet, that's been written in JSX/ES6.

```
import React from 'react'

class TextArea extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <textarea defaultValue={this.props.text}></textarea>
        <h3>{this.props.text.length}</h3>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

TextArea.propTypes = {
  text: React.PropTypes.string
}


export default TextArea;
```

Since this class was not generated with `React.createClass`, attempting to add `getInitialState` results in a big red console warning:

> Warning: getInitialState was defined on TextArea, a plain JavaScript class. This is only supported for classes created using React.createClass. Did you mean to define a state property instead?

How does one properly use the `getInitialState()` in an ES6 class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In class constructor need set `state` property

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {  }
}
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/26513/)

Comment: Recently learning React I came across this quote: [*NEVER mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were immutable*](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html). Then I read [this](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes) about ES6 classes :)

Answer (score 1):

For state you would just add `this.state = {}` inside your `constructor`. An example might be:

```
constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        placeHolder: 'Type your stuff here!'
        };
    }
```

For default Props, you would use `TextArea.defaultProps`. An example might be:

```
TextArea.defaultProps = {
    placeHolder: this.state.placeHolder
};
```

This goes outside your class, just as you have your validation check.